# Erro em um simples SELECT com Group By - SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte SELECT:

`SELECT P.Nome,P.TipoId,P.QuantidadeMensal FROM StockPhotos.Pacote P GROUP BY P.QuantidadeMensal;`

Porém estou recebendo essa mensagem de erro:

> Mensagem 8120, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 2
>
> Column 'StockPhotos.Pacote.Nome' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Não estou entendendo qual é o problema, pois `Nome` está sendo selecionado.

Comment: Qual o resultado você deseja? Não consegui entender direito, a princípio, o SQL server está agrupando somente por QuantidadeMensal e portanto,  assim que ele agrupa por quantidade mensal, ele não sabe o que fazer com TipoId e Nome pois não estão em uma função de agregação  ( não entendi exatamente o que você precisa também, por isso só consigo apontar o erro) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O SQL está dizendo que a coluna StockPhotos.Pacote.Nome deve:

1. Estar sendo computada com uma função de agregação, por exemplo `SUM` ou `COUNT`,  ou
2. Deve fazer parte do agrupamento, ou seja, deve estar no `GROUP BY`.

Basicamente, quando usamos `GROUP BY` **todos** os campos usados no `SELECT` devem, ou estar sendo usados em funções de agregação, ou devem também fazer parte do `GROUP BY`.

No seu caso, **apenas para ilustrar**, poderia usar assim (dois campos com count, e um no group by):

```
SELECT COUNT(P.Nome), COUNT(P.TipoId) ,P.QuantidadeMensal 
  FROM StockPhotos.Pacote P 
 GROUP BY P.QuantidadeMensal;
```

ou assim (todos os campos no group by):

```
SELECT P.Nome,P.TipoId,P.QuantidadeMensal 
  FROM StockPhotos.Pacote P 
 GROUP BY P.Nome,P.TipoId,P.QuantidadeMensal, P.QuantidadeMensal;
```

Isso são só exemplos, independente do resultado. Veja que não só P.Nome, mas também P.TipoId deve atender os mesmo critérios.

Comment: Perfeito, além da explicação solucionou um problema que eu tinha tentando agrupar pelo `Nome`, Ricardo, sua resposta foi **Pontual** (rsrs) !!

Answer (score 3):

Em tradução livre o erro diz:

> A coluna 'StockPhotos.Pacote.Nome' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não está contida nem em uma função agrupada nem na cláusula `GROUP BY`.

Ou seja, a coluna tem que estar no `GROUP BY` ou em uma função agrupada (`COUNT`, `AVG`, `SUM`, `MIN`, etc).

Você precisa indicar o que quer fazer com essa coluna ao `SQL Server`.

Comment: Explicou muito bem, obrigado aliás... +1

Answer (score 3):

Todo campo que retornar na consulta sem funções como SUM, AVG, etc devem estar no group by

Exemplo:

```
SELECT 
 P.Nome,P.TipoId,SUM(P.QuantidadeMensal) AS total 
FROM 
 StockPhotos.Pacote P 
GROUP BY 
  P.Nome,P.TipoId
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação ! nota 10 +1