# como posso pegar a ultima mensagem do meu campo `msg` com `GROUP BY`

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

boa noite, gostaria de saber como posso trazer a ultima mensagem do meu `group by`, pois não estou conseguindo. está trazendo sempre a primeira ocorrência da consulta e preciso pegar sempre a ultima mensagem daquele grupo. como posso fazer isso alguém poderia dar um help?

está é minha consulta

```
SELECT key_section, visualizado, msg, MAX(id_msg)
FROM chat 
GROUP BY key_section 
ORDER BY id_msg desc;
```

Comment: esse select não vai funcionar, todos os campos do select **devem** ter funções de agragação ou estar no group by:  `group by key_section, visualizado, msg`

Comment: aqui tem uma breve explicação disso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/320494/57220

Comment: Seria interessante identificar o que determina a ultima mensagem, vi que você tem key_section e id_msg, qual deles deve ser a chave? id_msg poderia ser simplesmente o identificador e key_section o sequencial, dessa forma o o key_section seria mais indicado, agora imagino que possa ter um campo DATA_HORA nessa tabela então a ultima mensagem poderia ser identificada por aí, concordando com o @Ricardo Pontual, todos os campos fora do MAX devem estar no group by, a pesar do MySQL não reclamar deve-se considerar o padrão SQL.

Answer (score 3):

### O Problema

Acontece que as colunas de `visualizado` e `msg` não estão sendo utilizadas no GROUP_BY e não estão sendo utilizadas por alguma função de agregação (SUM(), AVG(), etc..).

No MYSQL existe uma flag chamada `only_full_group_by`, caso ela estiver ativada, ao executar esta query será retornado um erro informando justamente que as colunas selecionadas não estão no group by ou em alguma função de agregação.

Caso ela esteja desativada a query será executada, porém não é garantido qual valor será retornado para as colunas que não atendem a condição do `group_by`. Por exemplo, suponha os seguintes registros:

```
+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+
| key_section | visualizado      | msg        | id_msg |
+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+
| 1           | 2019-09-03 08:32 | Mensagem 1 | 1      |
+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+
| 1           | 2019-09-05 17:00 | Mensagem 2 | 2      |
+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+
```

Agrupando por key_section (valor 1), qual resultado seria retornado nas outras colunas? Não é garantido a ordem de retorno dos resultados, o que pode lhe causar transtornos. A exceção a este caso ocorre quando você garantidamente possui o mesmo valor nas outras colunas, aí sim os resultados seriam "agrupados"

Talvez você poderia pensar em desabilitar a flag `only_full_group_by` porém isto só estaria escondendo o problema. Sem chances...

### Solução

Quando encontro um problema como este, utilizo uma solução conhecida por `greatest n per group` onde selecionamos os "grupos" e depois selecionamos os valores destes grupos.

No seu caso específico, eu escreveria a query desta maneira:

```
SELECT 
    max_chat.key_section,
    max_chat.id_msg,
    chat.visualizado,
    chat.msg
FROM
    chat
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        key_section, MAX(id_msg) AS id_msg
    FROM
        chat
    GROUP BY key_section) AS max_chat ON max_chat.key_section = chat.key_section
        AND chat.id_msg = max_chat.id_msg
ORDER BY max_chat.id_msg DESC;
```

Assim selecionaríamos todas as visualizações e as mensagens de cada `key_section` e seus maiores `id_msg`.

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais prática acredito que seja usando [`LIMIT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp):

```
SELECT key_section, visualizado, msg, id_msg
FROM chat 
ORDER BY id_msg desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Assim, será retornada apenas uma linha, ordenada de forma decrescente pelo `id_msg`.

Comment: Caso a flag `only_full_group_by` esteja habilitada, esta consulta irá retornar erro. As colunas de visualizado, msg e id_msg não estão descritas no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: tem razão, @SamuelTorga. De qualquer forma, o `group by` não é necessário. Alterei a resposta!