# Somar uma coluna por intervalos MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query, tabela-banco-de-dados

Pessoal tenho uma tabela no meu banco em MySQL assim:

Nome da tabela é `tb_cargaHora`

Estou tentando algo assim:

```
SELECT nome, matricula, SUM(carga_hora) FROM tb_cargaHora Order BY nome;
```

mas só aparece o resultado do `Andre`.

| id | nome | matrícula | discip | carga_hora |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Andre | 191131 | INF03 | 60 |
| 3 | Andre | 191131 | TEC01 | 60 |
| 4 | Julia | 203331 | CCI02 | 20 |
| 5 | Julia | 203331 | TEC01 | 60 |

Gostaria de somar somente a carga horária dos alunos deixando assim;

| nome | matricula | carga_hora |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Andre | 191131 | 120 |
| Julia | 203331 | 80 |

Comment: Pesquise por `GROUP BY`

Comment: como o @Woss pontou, precisa agrupar, veja essa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/320494/57220 ou aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/228296/57220

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Como cada aluno tem uma matricula unica, voce pode agrupar os dados pela matricula, assim no seu resultado terá a quantidade de linhas igual a quantidade de matriculas direntes, ou seja uma linha para cada aluno.

```
SELECT nome, matricula, SUM(carga_hora) FROM tb_cargaHora GROUP BY matricula Order BY nome;
```

Comment: Funcionou muito obrigado