# SELECT com COUNT e INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, inner-join

Estou realizando uma avalição de PL/SQL e o cenário seria o seguinte:
[Esta seriam as tabelas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28MpX.png)

Dado esse cenário, eu precisava realizar a seguinte consulta:
"Criar uma procedure para imprimir na tela o nome, CPF e quantidade de relacionados de todos os titulares."

Antes de finalizar a procedure, eu estava testando o select de diversas formas, mas não consegui contar a quantidade de relacionados.

Esse SELECT consegui trazer os dados que quero

```
SELECT DISTINCT`Titular`.`Nome_Titular`, `Titular`.`Cpf_Titular`
FROM `Titular` AS `Titular`
INNER JOIN `Relacionados` AS `Relacionados`
    ON `Titular`.`Idt_Titular` = `Relacionados`.`Idt_Titular`;
```

Mas tentando trazer a quantidade, não funcionou

```
SELECT DISTINCT`Titular`.`Nome_Titular`, `Titular`.`Cpf_Titular`, count(`Titular`.`Idt_Titular` = `Relacionados`.`Idt_Titular`) `Qtd_Relacionados`
FROM `Titular` AS `Titular`
INNER JOIN `Relacionados` AS `Relacionados`
    ON `Titular`.`Idt_Titular` = `Relacionados`.`Idt_Titular`;
```

Quem puder me ajudar, agradeço imensamente.

Comment: *"Mas tentando trazer a quantidade, não funcionou"* o que quer dizer com não funcionou? mas vejo que tem um `count` ai, e te falta um `group by`, dê uma olhada nisso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/320487/erro-em-um-simples-select-com-group-by-sql-server/320494#320494

Comment: Entendi Ricardo, eu testei dessa forma com group by e funcionou

https://www.invertexto.com/select

mas eu precisava adicionar mais uma coluna, e nela adicionar a quantidade de id's associados a outro id.

Isso seria possivel?
Obrigado por ajudar Ricardo!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema, eu precisava do seguinte SELECT.

```
SELECT `Titular`.`Nome_Titular`, `Titular`.`Cpf_Titular`,
    count(distinct  `Relacionados`.`Idt_Relacionado`)
FROM `Titular` AS `Titular`
INNER JOIN `Relacionados` AS `Relacionados`
ON `Titular`.`Idt_Titular` = `Relacionados`.`Idt_Titular`
GROUP BY `Nome_Titular`, `Cpf_Titular`;
```

Obrigado a todos.